# pattern to hide function

Tags: haskell

I often have pair of functions like this:

```
fooInner :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
fooInner 0 base accum = accum
fooInner num base accum = fooInner c base ([r] ++ accum)
                   where ....

foo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
foo a b = numNotationInner a b []
```

I have created 'foo' to more comfortable use of function. Instead of fooInner 10 4 [] I can use foo 10 4.

Is there any way to 'hide' fooInner inside foo to limit its scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you could just hide the guts in a `where` block:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
foo a b = fooInner a b [] where
    fooInner :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    fooInner 0 base accum = accum
    fooInner num base accum = fooInner c base ([r] ++ accum)
        where ...
```

Though there are a couple issues you might encounter doing this:

- If the implementation has multiple patterns, the `where` block will only apply to one of them:

  ```
  foo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
  foo 0 b = fooInner 1 b [] -- fooInner not in scope
  foo a b = fooInner a b [] where
      ... define fooInner ...
  ```

  Unless Haskell has some syntactic feature I don't know about, you'll have to do something like this if you still want to pattern match:

  ```
  foo a b = case (a, b) of
                 (0, b) -> fooInner 1 b []
                 (a, b) -> fooInner a b []
      where
          ... define fooInner ...
  ```

  I didn't test this.  You might have to tinker with the whitespace to get rid of syntax errors.
- If your function has polymorphic types, you may run into trouble trying to add a type signature to the inner function:

  ```
  foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
  foo f z = loop z where
      -- loop :: a -> [a] -- causes a type error
      loop z = z : loop (f z)
  ```

  The problem with the type signature `loop :: a -> [a]` is that, in its context, it doesn't truly work for **all** `a`, just the `a` corresponding to the arguments passed to `foo`.  Because it's using `f`, the type is bound to that `a`, meaning it can no longer work for any `a`.

  The simple solution here is to not use a type signature.  However, if you really want or even need a type signature, but adding one results in a type error, enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, and do this:

  ```
  foo :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
  foo f z = loop z where
      loop :: a -> [a]
      loop z = z : loop (f z)
  ```

  The `forall` extends the scope of `a` beyond its originating type signature to cover any type signatures appearing in the implementation.  This means that in `loop :: a -> [a]`, `a` is bound to the `a` in `foo`'s signature.